# Update Cloudformation stack name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CF stack in the name `gtm-test-commit-9ttyhf7old`. I want to know if there is a way to update the same stack with the new commit ID. Something like `gtm-test-commit-9ttyhf7new` without creating a new stack altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **not possible** to rename a stack. You have to delete it and create a new one with the name you want.

> For most resources, changing the logical name of a resource is
> equivalent to deleting that resource and replacing it with a new one.
> Any other resources that depend on the renamed resource also need to
> be updated and might cause to be replaced. Other resources require you
> to update a property (not just the logical name) in order to initiate
> an update.

Check out this doc: [AWS Official Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-get-template.html)